# How does one calculate Cohen's d and confidence intervals after logit in Stata?

Tags: confidence-interval, stata, effect-size, cohens-d

How does one calculate Cohen's d and confidence intervals after logit in Stata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the current issues with the user-written `sizefx` command for Stata that chl and I have uncovered, here's an alternative way of doing things in Stata using the user-written `metan` command. This is designed for meta-analysis of study-level summary data so you need to enter the means, sds and ns (which i've taken from chl's answer) in one row, then run a 'meta-analysis' on this single study (so the pooled SMD is the same as the SMD for the single study, and heterogeneity measures are undefined):.

```
input mean0 sd0 n0 mean1 sd1 n1

         mean0        sd0         n0      mean1        sd1         n1
  1. 23.66154  5.584522  130  22.30508  4.511496        59
  2. end

. list

     +------------------------------------------------------+
     |    mean0        sd0    n0      mean1        sd1   n1 |
     |------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 23.66154   5.584522   130   22.30508   4.511496   59 |
     +------------------------------------------------------+

. metan n1 mean1 sd1 n0 mean0 sd0, cohen

           Study     |     SMD   [95% Conf. Interval]     % Weight
---------------------+---------------------------------------------------
1                    | -0.257      -0.566     0.052        100.00
---------------------+---------------------------------------------------
I-V pooled SMD       | -0.257      -0.566     0.052        100.00
---------------------+---------------------------------------------------

  Heterogeneity chi-squared =   0.00 (d.f. = 0) p =    .
  I-squared (variation in SMD attributable to heterogeneity) =     .%

  Test of SMD=0 : z=   1.63 p = 0.103
```

The resulting point estimate and CI for Cohen's d agree with those that chl calculated by hand and using `ci.smd()` from R's MBESS library.

I'm less clear if this is entirely answering the original question, which asked to calculate Cohen's d *after `logit`*. But Cohen's d is one way of calculating the standardized mean difference, which I thought applied only to a continuous outcome measured in two groups. Perhaps the questioner could clarify.

Comment: @onestop (+1) Nice follow-up. My understanding of the question was "how to calculate an SMD in the case of a logistic regression?". Maybe worth clarifying that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thanks, these answers are incredibly helpful.  To clarify (hopefully), I intend to calculate the Cohen's d statistic for the difference in mean values of the predictions generated by a logit model.  I suspect that there are simpler ways to estimate the effect size of a logit model, but I want to compare results to a meta-analysis reporting Cohen's d.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Fred. I've looked up some old refs and an alternative way to convert a log-odds ratio (i.e. the coef for a binary variable in a logistic regression model) to an effect size comparable to Cohen's d is to multiply the logOR by √3/π. See:

Hasselblad V, Hedges LV.  Meta-analysis of screening and diagnostic tests.  Psychological Bulletin 1995; 117:167-178. http://content.apa.org/journals/bul/117/1/167

Chinn S.  A simple method for converting an odds ratio to effect size for use in meta-analysis.  Stat Med 2000;19:3127-3131. http://www3.interscience.wiley.com/cgi-bin/abstract/75500445

Comment: @Fred Still, it is not clear (sorry for that!) if your model includes a single predictor or more. In the latter case, SMDs are good summary statistics but they are not adjusted for other covariates of interest. @onestop I think there's a typo and you meant "the coef relating a predictor to the binary outcome" instead of "the coef for a binary variable...".

Comment: @chl Yes, thanks for the correction. Was a bit more than a typo to be honest, more of a thinko. This conversion requires some assumptions, of course - i think they amount to requiring that the predictor should have (approx) the same variance in those with and w/o the outcome after a transformation, if required, to make the distribution of the predictor approximately normal/logistic (strictly logistic, but the two are hard to distinguish without a huge dataset).

Comment: Thanks again for the helpful comments.  @chl The model has several independent variables.  Does that raise problems for my proposed method of calculating the Cohen's d on the difference in mean values of the logit predictions for "hits" and "misses"?

Comment: @Fred No. Just to say that in this case, you show crude estimates of effect size since they are not adjusted for other covariates. Odds-ratio are better in this respect, since they are adjusted.

Answer (score 8):

Cohen’s d is not directly available in Stata, and you have to resort on external macros, e.g. [sizefx](http://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s456738.htm) (`ssc install sizefx`). It works fine if you have to series of values, but I found it less handy when you work with a full data set because there's no possibility to pass options to this command (e.g. `by()`).

Anyway, you can still use the original formula (with pooled SDs),

$$
\delta_c=\frac{\bar x_1-\bar x_2}{s_p}
$$

where $s_p=\sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)s_1^2+(n_2-1)s_2^2)}{(n_1+n_2-2)}}$.

Here is an example by hand:

```
. webuse lbw
. logit low age smoke
. graph box age, by(low)
. tabstat age, by(low) statistics(mean sd N)

Summary for variables: age
     by categories of: low (birthweight<2500g)

     low |      mean        sd         N
---------+------------------------------
       0 |  23.66154  5.584522       130
       1 |  22.30508  4.511496        59
---------+------------------------------
   Total |   23.2381  5.298678       189
----------------------------------------

. display "Cohen's d: = " (23.66154-22.30508) / sqrt((129*(5.584522)^2+58*(4.511496)^2)/187)

Cohen's d: = .25714326
```

This is in agreement with what R would give:

```
library(MBESS)
res <- smd(Mean.1=23.66154, Mean.2=22.30508, 
           s.1=5.584522, s.2=4.511496, n.1=130, n.2=59)
ci.smd(smd=res, n.1=130, n.2=59, conf.level=0.95)
```

that is an effect size of 0.257 with 95% CI [-0.052;0.566].

In contrast, `sizefx` gives results that differ a little (I have use `separate age, by(low)` and collapse the results in a new data window, here two columns labeled `age0` and `age1`), the ES version calculated above corresponding to what is referred to as Hedge's g below (unless I miss something in the [code](http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/s/sizefx.ado) I read):

```
. sizefx age0 age1

Cohen's d and Hedges' g for: age0 vs. age1
Cohen's d statistic (pooled variance) = .26721576
Hedges' g statistic = .26494154

Effect size correlation (r) for: age0 vs. age1
ES correlation r = .13243109
```

Comment: +1 esp as you gave a link, and hence traceability and attribution!

Comment: @onestop Any idea for the difference between the two series of results?

Comment: @chi Oh dear, I think -sizefx- contains a coding error! It's ignoring the values of one variable for which the other variable is missing (the problem is with the use of -marksample-). I'll contact the author. I've never used it before myself (i'm relieved to say...)

Comment: You also make a good point that it would be better if -sizefx- supported a "by()" option. I'm also not sure why it's referring to Cohen's d as Hedges' g. The latter really involves a more complex bias correction. All in all, i'd advise against using -sizefx- for the time being!

Comment: @onestop (+1) Good to hear that you spotted the problem (not enough Stata experience myself). Anyway, the distinction between Cohen's d and Hedges's g is rather confusing, even on Wikipedia (I admit this is not really a reference, though). In addition to not supporting a `by()` option, no CIs are computed (we'd need to rely on a non-central $t$ distribution, or use some kind of bootstrap approach).